# trabajando con archivos externos csv y python 3

Tags: python, csv, python-3.7

estoy haciendo ejercicios de importación de archivos csv, el archivo es muy corto y el código tendría que devolverme la persona de más edad, pero me da una distinta, he bicheado por ahí la parte final del código no la entiendo, el archivo es éste

```
id,name,age,height,weight
1,Alice,20,62,120.6
2,Freddie,21,74,190.6
3,Bob,17,68,120.0
```

Y el código, éste

```
import csv
inputfile=csv.DictReader(open("people.csv" ))
maxage = None
oldestperson = None
for row in inputfile :
    age = int(row["age"])
    if maxage==None or maxage < age :
        maxage = age
        oldestperson=row["name"]

if maxage!= None :
    print ('La persona más mayor es  %s, que tiene  %d anos.' % (oldestperson,maxage))
else :
    print ('El fichero no contiene datos.')
```

resultado

```
La persona más mayor es  Bob, que tiene  17 anos.
```

No entiendo que si pone edad máxima haga el comparativo con < y tampoco entiendo el último if. Además el resultado es erróneo, pues es Fredy la persona de más edad
Gracias de antemano y un saludo

Comment: ¿qué es bichear? Por favor, utiliza el Castellano.

Comment: ¿Y si pone `age > maxage` lo entiendes mejor? Es la misma comparación. Y el código sí que funciona (lo he probado y me produce como resultado Freddy, de 21 años)

Comment: ¿Porqué inicias `maxage` en None? Mejor iniciarlo en 0 (nadie puede tener menos de 0 años) y así te ahorras la comparación `maxage == None`. Por otro lado, deberías mostrar por pantalla, en cada iteración, lo que estás almacenando en la variable `age` y lo que contiene `maxage`, justo antes de la sentencia `if`, así sabrás lo que estás comparando. Saludos

Comment: Lo he vuelto a hacer correr y me da resultado, pero no entiendo el último if, no hace falta

Comment: Lo probe y me dio "Freddie" como resultado.

Comment: Sí, a mí también, pero no entiendo el último if

Comment: no entiendes if maxage!= None? entonces se claro, y di no entiendo que hace esta linea. Esa linea se esta fijando si esa variable cambio de valor o no...

Comment: En cierto sentido tienes razón y la línea `if maxage!=None` podría sobrar, ya que basta que el fichero tenga una sola fila para que `maxage` tome el valor de la edad en esa fila. La única razón por la que `maxage` podría llegar ahí siendo todavía `None` sería que el CSV no contuviera datos. Ah, y ya de paso,  no se recomienda usar `!=` para comparar con `None`, sino `if maxage is not None:`

Comment: ¿Puedes utilizar Pandas?, para trabajar con .csv es muy eficaz y sería muy fácil obtener la menor edad.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacer un par de pequeños cambios, para que no te confundas...

> Iniciar maxage en -1

> En el if, cambiar (maxage < age) por (age > maxage)

Todo el código esta comentado...

```
import csv

inputfile = csv.DictReader( open("people.csv" ) )   # Cargas los datos del csv en inputfile

maxage = -1                 # Inicias la edad en -1, nadie tiene años negativos
oldestperson = None         # El nombre de la persona lo inicias en «nan», sin una valor particular

for row in inputfile :      # Inicia el ciclo leyendo cada fila del "archivo" csv
    age = int(row["age"])   # En age guardas la edad, cada vez que se lee una fila, la edad de esa fila es guardada en "age"

    # Para  que no te confundas cambiamos (maxage < age) por (age > maxage)
    if age > maxage:        # Aqui preguntas si la fila con el valor age es mayor a la edad guardada en maxage, 
                            # En el primer ciclo maxage es -1 (si existen datos en el csv)
                            # y obligatoriamente entra en el if, ya que siempre existe una edad mayor a -1
        maxage = age        # maxage queda con el valor de la primera fila del csv
        oldestperson = row["name"]
                            # En el resto de ciclos se compara, si el valor de age es mayor maxage, si es asi
                            # se entrara al if, y maxage cambiara su valor, a valor de age (ya que age es mayor)

if maxage == -1:            # Aqui preguntamos si maxage tiene alguna edad, si no es asi seguira en -1, por consiguiente no hay valores en el csv
    print ('El fichero no contiene datos.')
else:                       # De lo contrario, si maxage tiene algun valor diferente a -1, se muestran los datos
    print ('La persona más mayor es  %s, que tiene  %d años.' % (oldestperson, maxage))
```